# How computer present number or a character on console

Tags: binary, pixel

I know that the computer restore all information in terms of 0,1 so for example when I declare variable in any programming language and assign number 5 to it, my question is how the number 5 is present on the console, in other word, how computer draw the number 5 on the screen, if the number is just restored on the memory in term of 0,1 in 8 byte ram.

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside the computer works like that. You input a number or string, it's being stored like zeros and ones and then decoded back when it reaches your screen.

It's interesting to read about the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code. So if you want to find the how many letter apart is A to F you need to find their ASCII (given that this encoding is used) codes and do the subtraction.

Usually more problem oriented questions are expected (rather that CS theory). Have a [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on that too. I am happy to talk theory but it's important to respect the stackoverflow guidelines.